# iOS -- UITextView disable scrolling but enable touches

Tags: ios, iphone, scroll, uitextview, text-cursor

Is there any way to do this?

What I really want is a UITextField where I can control the location of the cursor.  But as far as I can tell, that is impossible.  So I am looking at using a UITextView.  This does allow one to control the cursor location.  But scrolling is getting in the way -- my text is scrolling here and there, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I set scrollEnabled to NO and have an empty implementation of scrollRectToVisible:animated:, it appears to disable scrolling.

Comment: Won't the touches get disabled in this case also?

Answer (score 18):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can prevent the view from scrolling by setting the property *scrollEnabled* to *NO*.

Comment: The problem is that this also disables touches.

Comment: Ahh in that case you could set up the next responder in the responder chain to handle touch events, or perhaps better - attach a UIGestureRecogizer to it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid . . .

Comment: @WilliamJockusch i am facing same issue

Answer (score 11):

Just set the UITextView’s content size to be less than or equal to its bounds, this will prevent scrolling and still accept touch events.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**, **Swift 4**:

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: isScrollEnabled will also reset the position of the view to the beginning