# Action for NSTextView and block scroll

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

In my Mac app I've a `NSTableView` and for each row I created a custom cell like follow:

[image]

Now I need to block the scroll of the `NSTextView` and do some action if user press on the `NSTextView`.

I tried to use a `NSTextField`, but it doesn't work for me because the text I should put in the `NSTextView` must have much than one row.
Does anyone know how to block the scroll of the `NSTextView` and add an action on it? Thank you

Comment: UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can prevent the view from scrolling by setting the property scrollEnabled to NO. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413248/ios-uitextview-disable-scrolling-but-enable-touches

Comment: ehm... It's a Mac app not an iOS app... I can't use the method `scrollEnabled`